# How can I Pass Name & Country from Entry Item

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I am developer a Apps which contain Various Name & Country List. I want to pass Employee Name & Country name to another activity on click on Child Item of **Expandable ListView**.

How to set On Click Listener Method on my Activity?

```
package nasir.main.activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import nasir.adapter.EntryItem;
import nasir.adapter.MyListAdapter;
import nasir.adapter.SectionItem;
import nasir.bd.poem.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.SearchView;


public class Employee_List extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

    Button Collapse;
    Button Expand;

    private SearchView search;
    private MyListAdapter listAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView myList;
    private ArrayList<SectionItem> section = new ArrayList<SectionItem>();
    ArrayList<EntryItem> items = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
    ExpandableListView expandableList = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.poem_list);


        expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
        Expand = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Expand);
        Collapse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Collapse);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        search.setOnCloseListener(this);

        Collapse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                      myList.collapseGroup(i);
                     }
                Collapse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Expand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


         Expand.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                      myList.expandGroup(i);
                     }
                Expand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Collapse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });


        // display the list
        displayList();
        // expand all Groups
//      expandAll();

         collapseAll();

    }



    // method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            myList.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }

     //method to Collapse all groups
     private void collapseAll() {
     int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
     myList.collapseGroup(i);
     }
     }

    // method to expand all groups
    private void displayList() {

        // display the list
        load_Part_1_Data();


        // get reference to the ExpandableListView
        myList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
        // create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
        listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(Poem_List.this, section);
        // attach the adapter to the list
        myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        myList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3, long arg4) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Poem_List.this, Details_Information.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }




    private void load_Part_1_Data() {


        items = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
        section.add(new SectionItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "", items));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Margerate Milan", "Computer Operator", getString(R.string.app_name)));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Abraham Jhon", "Salse Man", getString(R.string.app_name)));

        items = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
        section.add(new SectionItem(R.drawable.blank_image, "", items));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "England", "Europe", getString(R.string.app_name)));
        items.add(new EntryItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Japan", "Asia", getString(R.string.app_name)));



    }



    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        listAdapter.filterData("");
        expandAll();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        listAdapter.filterData(query);
        expandAll();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        listAdapter.filterData(query);
        expandAll();
        return false;
    }

}
```

**MyListAdapter.Class**

```
package nasir.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import nasir.bd.poem.R;
import nasir.main.activity.Details_Information;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SectionItem> continentList;
    private ArrayList<SectionItem> originalList;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionItem> continentList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.continentList = new ArrayList<SectionItem>();
        this.continentList.addAll(continentList);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<SectionItem>();
        this.originalList.addAll(continentList);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<EntryItem> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getSectionList();
        return countryList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        final EntryItem country = (EntryItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }

        ImageView Rank = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Rank);
        TextView Poem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Poem);
        TextView Poetry = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Poetry);


        Rank.setImageResource(country.getRank());
        Poem.setText(country.getPoem().trim());
        Poetry.setText(country.getPoetry().trim());

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Details_Information.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            intent.putExtra("header", country.getDetails_Doc());
            context.startActivity(intent); 

        }
    });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        ArrayList<EntryItem> countryList = continentList.get(groupPosition).getSectionList();
        return countryList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return continentList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return continentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        SectionItem continent = (SectionItem) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
        }

        TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        heading.setText(continent.getName().trim());

        ImageView Group_icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Group_Icon);
        Group_icon.setImageResource(continent.getIcon());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void filterData(String query) {

        query = query.toLowerCase();
        Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size()));
        continentList.clear();

        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            continentList.addAll(originalList);
        } else {

            for (SectionItem continent : originalList) {

                ArrayList<EntryItem> countryList = continent.getSectionList();
                ArrayList<EntryItem> newList = new ArrayList<EntryItem>();
                for (EntryItem country : countryList) {
                    if (country.getPoem().toLowerCase().contains(query) || country.getPoetry().toLowerCase().contains(query) )  {
                        newList.add(country);
                    }
                }
                if (newList.size() > 0) {
                    SectionItem nContinent = new SectionItem(continent.getIcon(), continent.getName(), newList);
                    continentList.add(nContinent);
                }
            }
        }

        Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size()));
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Employee_List  activity , you can access the data through index of child and group obtaining from ChildClickListener

```
myList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3, long arg4) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Here You can access the child data by
                final EntryItem country = (EntryItem) listAdapter .getChild(arg2, arg3);
                //From here you can pass the data through Intent

                ...

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks Brother.
It Works Correctly.

Comment: Glad to hear that Brother :-)